# Where should I ask about Docker/Django configuration?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm having issues getting my Django app to serve through my Docker container. I'm wondering if there's a specific Stack Exchange site for this type of configuration issue or if I should just post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you even consider to do some [research](https://www.google.de/search?q=stack+exchange+docker+questions&oq=stack+exchange+docker+questions) before asking here? Check the top result.

Comment: Yes. I googled that exact thing. And saw that there were 5 links to 5 different sites so I came here. There was absolutely no need to be snarky here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) is currently in beta. That seems like a likely place. In fact, [docker](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker) is their most popular tag.